# Why does MariaDB choose different index use for the same data?

Tags: index, mariadb

I have this table (this is the output from `show create table` on both servers, ie. using `diff` to compare the output shows only the auto increment value, because one has moved on slightly from the snapshot).

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(39) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `method` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `endpoint` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `status` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `params` text,
  `data` mediumtext,
  `client_username` varchar(526) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ip` varchar(39) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra_params` text,
  `error_code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `request_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `domain_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `request_id` (`request_id`),
  KEY `endpoint` (`endpoint`),
  KEY `method` (`method`),
  KEY `client_username` (`client_username`(255)),
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `admin_id` (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=685835441 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have exactly the same data on two different servers (both have the same my.cnf), but I get different behaviour. On one, I get a table scan, no matter what, and on the other I get the expected index use (not just with the domain_id index as in the example below, but with *any* index).

On the good one:

```
MariaDB [temp_db]> explain select * from logs where domain_id=298506;
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | logs            | ref  | domain_id     | domain_id | 9       | const | 119987 |       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

On the bad one:

```
MariaDB [temp_db]> explain select * from logs where domain_id=298506;
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | logs            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 166719856 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

They are both using MariaDB 10.1.29, on Debian. I've done an optimise table and analyse table on both.

Asking MariaDB to force use of the index also doesn't:

```
MariaDB [temp_db]> explain select * from logs force index (domain_id) where domain_id=298506;
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | logs            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 167509512 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there either some explanation for what causes this behaviour, or some way that I can investigate further?

Comment: How many rows are total and selected by this query on each server separately? i.e. show results for `select count(*), count(distinct domain_id), sum(domain_id=298506) from logs` for each server.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an index on `(domain_id)` on the "bad" server/table? `possible_keys: NULL` suggests there isn't.

Comment: Yes, the indexes (the entire create table, it was from a mysqldump snapshot, and I've verified) are exactly the same on both.

Comment: @akina bad server: `count(*)`=167122005,`count(d di)`=160512,`sum(d id=298506)`=97077. Good server: `count(*)`=157920128, `c(d di)`=154300, `sum(d id)`=96866. They have diverged a bit (the bad server is in production, the good one is a snapshot elsewhere), but the problem existed when they were identical as well.

Comment: Does forcing the ``KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`)`` index alters explain on "bad" server to a form which you see on "good" one? `explain select * from logs force index (domain_id) where domain_id=298506;`

Comment: @akina Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'd tried that and it didn't help. Updated the post.

Comment: What's the datatype for `client_username`?

Comment: What is the output of: `select constraint_name, table_name, column_name from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema = ... and table_name = 'logs';` from both databases?

Answer (score 1):

- This should temporarily fix the statistics that appear to be screwed up:  Do `ANALYZE TABLE logs;`; it will take a long time (for MyISAM, but not for InnoDB).
- Run `CHECK TABLE logs;` -- the index may be corrupted.  (This is a MyISAM-only thing to do.)
- Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  InnoDB does not need `ANALYZE TABLE` nearly as often, and the `ANALYZE` runs much faster.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I've already tried analyse and it didn't help. I've checked the table as well.